# Dynamic Pivot with column names from dynamic tables

Tags: sql-server, xml, dynamic, reporting-services, pivot

I am working on a project with SSRS and Rockwell Software's RSView32. Basically this software project logs manufacturing data to individual tables as such:

One table (Machine1_TagTable) has Tag names which describe the data as such: TagName, TagIndex. The name provides a human-understandable reference to the information contained in a second table. Example : Part Number, 1

The second table (Machine1_FloatTable) contains raw data with nothing more than a timestamp, TagIndex and value.
Example : 2013-12-10 15:44:11.322, 1, 12345(value)

I have a dynamic pivot which works for ONE table; however, I would like to use a variable parameter passed from SSRS to select both the TagTable and FloatTable.

This works with the Machine1_FloatTable as part of the dynamic statement, but not in the XML path building. I understand this is a scope issue, so I'm looking for creative ways to allow me to pass the table names from SSRS into this stored procedure.

Here's what I have now:

```
DECLARE @FLOATTABLE NVARCHAR(MAX), @TAGTABLE NVARCHAR(MAX), @startdate NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@enddate NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols as NVARCHAR(MAX), @query as NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @TAGTABLE ='dbo.Machine1_TagTable'
SET @FLOATTABLE = 'dbo.Machine1_FloatTable'


SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' +  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,TagName),'"')
FROM @tagtable
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')


Set @query = 'SELECT  DISTINCT DateAndTime, Millitm,  ' + @cols + ' FROM ( select
T.DateAndTime, T.Millitm, N.TagName, T.Val from ' + @FLOATTABLE + ' T  LEFT JOIN ' +
@TAGTABLE + ' N ON T.TagIndex=N.TagIndex WHERE T.DateAndTime Between '''+ @startdate +
'''     AND '''+ @enddate +''')  x PIVOT (MAX(Val) for TagName IN (' + @cols + ')) p'

PRINT (@query)
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's possible, if I understand your question.  You have to build a dynamic SQL string, and execute that to populate @cols.

```
declare @string nvarchar(MAX)

set @String = 'SELECT STUFF((SELECT  DISTINCT   '','' +  QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR,ActualDate),' 
    + '''"'') FROM ' + @TAGTABLE + ' FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,1,'''')'


EXECUTE sp_executeSQL @String, @Cols OUTPUT

print @cols
```

It's pretty hacky, but I think it should work.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I had earlier attempted this but apparently had issues with the quote escapes. The query now executes without errors but only returns the first result set (@cols).

Comment: Escaping quotes is misery.  I didn't include the rest of your code in mine.  You should be able to build your @query variable as you have it above and then execute it using sp_executesql.